# Remove certain observations based on two criteria

Tags: dataframe

all the rows that have observations for the same date and Key are marked.

```
#Data
 Key   Date   Value       ...other columns
 C    2000-04   0.55         name1     x1   <- 
 C    2000-04   0.60         name2     x2   <-
 C    2000-05   1.2
 A    2001-06   4
 A    2001-07   5
 A    2002-08   2
```

Ist there an easy way to remove those observations instead of summing them up?

Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `duplicated` twice, one with the default `fromLast = FALSE` and the other setting `fromLast = TRUE`.
Then, negate that result index.

```
inx <- duplicated(Data[c('Key', 'Date')]) | duplicated(Data[c('Key', 'Date')], fromLast = TRUE)

Data[!inx, ]
#  Key    Date Value
#3   C 2000-05   1.2
#4   A 2001-06   4.0
#5   A 2001-07   5.0
#6   A 2002-08   2.0
```

**Data.**

```
Data <-
structure(list(Key = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", 
"C"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L), .Label = c("2000-04", "2000-05", "2001-06", "2001-07", "2002-08"
), class = "factor"), Value = c(0.55, 0.6, 1.2, 4, 5, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I understand correctly. If yes, a very simple answer is unique() function.

First, you need to have very strong reason to remove these duplications.

```
Key  <- c("C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C")
Value <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1)
df <- data.frame(Key, Value)
unique(df)
```